# How do I pre-populate Glide cache?

Tags: android, android-glide

I have an application that allows users to display photos.  It is using Glide to download them.

When a user creates a photo locally, they can see it, instantly, in the application, because the app knows where the local file is.

Eventually, though, I have to upload the photo so that it is available to other users on other devices.  All devices, including the one that created the photo now use the URI for the uploaded file.  That means that the first time the device that *created* the photo views it, after it is uploaded, there is an annoying delay while the photo is downloaded again, redundantly.  (After that is is in Glide's cache)

The application uploads the photo from the local file to its location behind the globally available URI.  At that time it knows both the path to to local file and the URI from which it will, eventually, be downloaded.

I would *love* to be able, at that point, to pre-populate Glide's cache for the download URI, with the contents of the file.  No redundant download; no annoying delay.

I've poked at Glide a little bit and I just don't see how to get it to do that.

Comment: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#cache-keys. They say this: `The model the load is requested for (File, Uri, Url) (If you are using a custom model, it needs to correctly implements hashCode() and equals()`. I assume that they mean the Load model is the main key. if you customize the load model, by overriding `hashCode` and `equals` so that the new uploaded Uri equals to the cache Uri, Glide may look for the match custom load model in the cache and load it like what you need.